# Package fontspec Error: The font "Fontin-SmallCaps" cannot be found

Tags: fonts

I am compile a resume using xelatex, the font define like this:

```
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
% Main document font
\setmainfont[
  Extension = .otf ,
  UprightFont = *-regular ,
  BoldFont = *-bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-italic ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic ,
  SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps
]{texgyretermes}
```

when I compile, she log shows error like this:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-ge
neric.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-xe
luatex.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))

! Package fontspec Error: The font "Fontin-SmallCaps" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.26

?
```

I have already download the font and copied into the system path:

```
ubuntu@VM-0-16-ubuntu:/usr/share/fonts/opentype/reddwarfcv$ ls Fontin*
Fontin-Bold.otf  Fontin-Italic.otf  Fontin-Regular.otf  Fontin-SmallCaps.otf
```

Am I missing something? I have tried to re-run fc-cache command.

Comment: Does the same code work if you put the font-file in your working-directory?

Comment: does it work with lualatex?

Comment: when I copied the font file to working directory, it works. @Niranjan

Comment: you probably need to re-run fc-cache

Comment: I tried to re-run fc-cache but still could not work.

Comment: @Dolphin From the shear amount of questions you post, it seems that fonts with xelatex cause you a lot of trouble. Did you already give lualatex a try? It is often better at finding fonts.

Comment: I have to use xelatex, because all the template I am finding using xelatex.

Comment: Did you actually try to use lualatex? Most things which work in xelatex also work in lualatex. And even if something does not work with lualatex, it might be easier to fix than your constant font problems.

Comment: if I use lualatex, I have to change all my template code, I have tried lualatex and shows error `! Critical Package xeCJK Error: The xeCJK package requires XeTeX to function`. I have so many template. It will be hard to replace with lualaex.

Comment: @Dolphin In this case it would be best if your questions would include a small test file which include the packages relevant to font you use.